# updating content of webpage from database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using php to upload data to database and using php to display data from database.

In the script below, I use php to display all content from database. Each row in database table will be displayed in a `<div>` element and a `<p>` element is used to contain each column in a row.

But the script actually never run! I spotted the error is because of the symbol `>` at the end of each tag in `echo` statement, for example:

The `>` in the statement `echo "<div class="post">";`

if I delete this `>` symbol, then the next `>` causes the same problem.

In the beginning, I thought this is because of the quotes, but I tried '' instead of "" in echo statement but I still got the same problem. So what exactly the way to use HTML tag in php code?

I think I get some misunderstanding here.

This is the full script:

```
            <div class="dashboardA">
                <?php
                    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Dave", "password");
                    if (!$con){
                        die ("Could not connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    }
                    mysqli_select_db($con, "snippet");

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from persons");

                    while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array("$sql")){
                        echo "<div class="post">";
                        echo "<p>"; echo $data["FirstName"]; echo "</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
'; echo "
" . $data["FirstName"] . "

"; echo "
"; } ?>
```

Comment: you must escape your doule quotes (") inside your html strings.
For example: echo "<div class="post">"; must become echo "<div class=\"post\">"; OR echo '<div class="post">';

Comment: Change `echo "<div class="post">";` to `echo "<div class=\"post\">";` or `echo "<div class='post'>";`

Comment: I hope your password isn't "password"

Comment: @Strawberry ah this is just a testing database so ... :) you know :) using wamp server

Comment: what are the difference between `echo "<div class='post'>"` and `echo '<div class="post">';` ??

Comment: You can also shorten `echo "<p>"; echo $data["FirstName"]; echo "</p>";` to a single echo'ed line `echo "<p>" . $data["FirstName"] . "</p>";`

Comment: or just echo "<p>{$data['FirstName']}</p>";

Comment: I tried these solutions but I still can't get my script to work ... still showing code on the page, please look at the output in edit

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array("$sql")){
                    echo "<div class=\"post\">";
                    echo "<p>"; echo $data["FirstName"]; echo "</p>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
```

Notice, that the change was not using ' class="post"> ', you should better use ' class=\"post\"> '.

It's just that simple, that the way you did, you simply took of the "post" word from the echo string, with the " \ " sign you mark the ' " ' signs as a part of the string.

Hope I could help and solve the problem, peace.

Did you tryout what I wrote? That should work actually.

Comment: What about chaning 
' echo "<p>"; echo $data["FirstName"]; echo "</p>"; ' to that:

echo "<p>" . $data["FirstName"] . "</p>";

Comment: no it doesn't work. I tried it already. The problem comes from this character `>`, it's not about the quotes ...

Comment: I used view page source in chrome and I see 2 different colors in php block. This means that there are some syntax errors in the php block, but I just don't know how to fix it at all. I'm a beginner in php ...

Comment: Then I dont know if this might help, but replace ">" with "&gt;".

Its the normal html encoding for the ">" sign.
The other one would be "&lt;".

Tell me if this works

Comment: well nothing is displayed on the webpage ... Thanks for your help anw :)

Comment: Then there might be a database (or it's values?) error dunno, but if there is no more code on the page you can continue I guess:P

You're welcome buddy

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                        echo '<div class="post">';
                        echo '<p>' . $data["FirstName"] . '</p>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
```

Be careful with quotes  and use dot symbol to concat strings.